# ASP Classic CDOSYS

Tags: asp-classic

We are having issues sending an XML file via email using CDOSYS. The problem (we suspect) is too many headers on the outgoing email.
Our old emailer (SMTP Mailer) had the following setting "UseMSMailHeaders" set to false which resulted in minimal headers on the outgoing mail. We are looking to add this same setting to the CDOSYS to achieve the same minimal headers - however there is no such configuration setting for CDOSYS.

The working email headers (created using SMTP Mailer) were as follows:

```
X-mailer: Asp Component Bundle 4.03 (COMB63E607)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

The email headers (created using CDOSYS) are now:

```
X-Originating-IP: [82.11.130.88]
X-Spam: 0
X-Authority: v=2.1 cv=Rs1LLUWK c=1 sm=1 tr=0 a=NcIbe7jg/PruPBS/SkG5Ow==:117
 a=NcIbe7jg/PruPBS/SkG5Ow==:17 a=OZ8DCac85m8A:10 a=uObrxnre4hsA:10
 a=NLZqzBF-AAAA:8 a=KQ9VrMxVm9wA:10 a=r77TgQKjGQsHNAKrUKIA:9 a=9iDbn-4jx3cA:10
 a=cKsnjEOsciEA:10 a=WzHNiX6cKY2DZ1D7HSYA:9 a=SSmOFEACAAAA:8 a=e0m2sKwKAAAA:8
 a=LDuhtmgyDqFV3yBKdvUA:9 a=wVYsaH73nbqcsVgb:21 a=p8LqAaNAe91_BBSR:21
 a=zJJgJrR4LD4A:10 a=ZHtQ2jxvbGEA:10 a=JiXicNB2fugA:10
X-Priority: 1
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
thread-index: Ac8vaWtRWKRVMRvtReSO2cdupviJVQ==
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0009_01CF2F69.6B518590"
X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000
Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message
Importance: normal
Priority: normal
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.1.7601.17609
```

I notice that the CDOSYS email Content-Type is set to "multipart/mixed" even though our ASP code has the following line:

```
Set Mailer = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item (http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/content-type") = "text/xml"
```

Is this normal behaviour?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is too many headers? A good mail transport agent (MTA) **should** provide detailed headers. Maybe what you mean to ask is something along the lines of: I changed how I build and transmit my SMTP messages and now they all bounce.  Is something like that happening? If not, try to elaborate on the details of the nature of the true underlying problem further.

As for the second part of your message, if you attach a file, the content type will change automatically.

Comment: Attaching the file was my problem, I removed the attachment and now it works as intended. Thankyou dmarietta.